# CSS - inline not working with position absolute

Tags: css, html

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: h2 style problems]
**HTML:**
`<h2>Some text<br /> even more text</h2>`

**CSS**

*Works*

```
display: inline;
line-height: 1.7em;
font-size: 65px;
color: #333;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

*Doesn't work*

```
display: inline;
line-height: 1.7em;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
z-index: 2;
font-size: 65px;
color: #333;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you update the code to show the name of the class, id, or element you are targetting with the css? Also in case of id or class, also add it to the html.

Answer (score 2):

`inline` implicitly becomes `block` when you absolutely position an element, see

[Css 2.1, 9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

You will need to use an additional inline element inside this heading, if you want to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps:

- Wrap each part of the `<h2>` heading in a `<span>`
- Give each `span` a `display` of `inline-block`
- Apply the `box-shadow` to each `span`

**Working Example:**

```css
h2:nth-of-type(1) {
display: inline;
line-height: 1.7em;
font-size: 18px;
color: #333;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

h2:nth-of-type(2) {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
z-index: 2;
color: #333;
background-color: #FFF;
}

h2:nth-of-type(2) span {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 18px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<h2>Some text<br />even more text</h2>
<h2><span>Some text</span><br /><span>even more text</span></h2>
```